# How to swap a long variable present in list of a class with swap method

Tags: c#

I have a list `public List<ArticleWarehouseLocations> ArticleWarehouseLocationsList`. In this list I have a property called `Position`.

```
`Swap<long>(ref ArticleWarehouseLocationsList[currentIndex].Position, ref ArticleWarehouseLocationsList[currentIndex - 1].Position);`
    public void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
     {
       T temp = lhs;
       lhs = rhs;
       rhs = temp;
      }
```

I'm trying to do something like this. It's giving me an error property or index may not be passed as ref or out.

I can use a local variable and assign it the value and use it but I'm looking for a global solution.

Comment: What is the type of `ArticleWarehouseLocationsList[currentIndex]` ?

Comment: And if you have a *property* named `Position`, then you can't pass that as a ref to anything. That's simply not possible. You will have to copy the values to local variables, and then call swap. If the property returns a `ref` value, then perhaps.

Comment: ... or, if you're in a newer C# compiler, you can do this: `(ArticleWarehouseLocationsList[currentIndex].Position, ArticleWarehouseLocationsList[currentIndex - 1].Position) = (ArticleWarehouseLocationsList[currentIndex - 1].Position, ArticleWarehouseLocationsList[currentIndex].Position);` which is basically `(x, y) = (y, x);`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen ArticleWarehouseLocations this is the type and from u r 2 comment I got that i can't do like this  thanks

Comment: With the introduction of tuple syntax in C# 7, you no longer need a dedicated swap method, simply write `(x, y) = (y, x);` and you're done. This should work with variables and properties alike.

Comment: (x, y) = (y, x) and I'm working with 4.5 I think tuples won't support in this.i will use local varibale

Comment: Tuple syntax is supported in .NET 4.5 if you use C# 7, however the tuple *values* need a nuget package. `(x, y) = (y, x);` does in fact not use any special runtime types and will actually expand to what you had in your swap method which is supported in any runtime.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is make the property return by reference:

```
class Obj {
    private long pos;
    public ref long Position { get { return ref pos; } }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Obj[] arr = new Obj[2] { new Obj(), new Obj() };

        arr[0].Position = 10;
        arr[1].Position = 20;

        int index = 0;

        WriteLine($"{arr[index].Position}, {arr[index+1].Position}");
        Swap<long>(ref arr[index].Position, ref arr[index+1].Position);
        WriteLine($"{arr[index].Position}, {arr[index+1].Position}");
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns

Comment: sry I need use the `currentIndex` the one u mentioned is just a swap method

Comment: it was about swapping properties, not about arrays. Here you go, changed it into arrays

Comment: is there any way to make it work without this  `public ref long Position { get { return ref pos; }`  i cant modify this class `ArticleWarehouseLocations` i just have the .dll  files

Answer (score 1):

I believe the tuple swap `(x, y) = (y, x)` proposed in comments is the way to go, but wanted to share yet another aproach with LINQ Expressions (a bit too long for a comment, so posting as an answer)

```cs
public static void SwapProperties<T>(T lhs, T rhs, Expression<Func<T, object>> propExpression)
{
    var prop = GetPropertyInfo(propExpression);
    var lhsValue = prop.GetValue(lhs);
    var rhsValue = prop.GetValue(rhs);
    prop.SetValue(lhs, rhsValue);
    prop.SetValue(rhs, lhsValue);
}

private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> propExpression)
{
    PropertyInfo prop;
    if (propExpression.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression)
    {
        prop = (PropertyInfo) memberExpression.Member;
    }
    else
    {
        var op = ((UnaryExpression) propExpression.Body).Operand;
        prop = (PropertyInfo) ((MemberExpression) op).Member;
    }
    return prop;
}

class Obj
{
    public long Position { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a1 = new Obj()
    {
        Position = 10,
        Name = "a1"
    };
    var a2 = new Obj()
    {
        Position = 20,
        Name = "a2"
    };
    SwapProperties(a1, a2, obj => obj.Position);
    SwapProperties(a1, a2, obj => obj.Name);

    Console.WriteLine(a1.Position);
    Console.WriteLine(a2.Position);

    Console.WriteLine(a1.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(a2.Name);
}
```